# How to register ASP.NET on Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I got the following error when I run this command: `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
>   Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0 Administration
>   utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Start
>   installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0). This option is not supported on this
>   version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead
>   install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows
>   Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the
>   dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771. Finished installing
>   ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

This is my Windows Features configurations:
[image]

Comment: what did you do as fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx), **you need at least .NET 4.6 to be compatible with Windows 10**.

Comment: That error message comes from a piece of code written for .NET Framework 4.5, which Microsoft seems to hesitate to upgrade solely for .NET Framework 4.6.x/4.7.x. So end users should be smart enough to read it as ".NET 4.6" or ".NET 4.7" based on the operating system they use. Your answer has an improper part. It is not ".NET 4.6 to be compatible with Windows 10", but "Windows 10 ships with .NET 4.6 by default", and its Creators Update starts to ship .NET 4.7.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. Does your answer mean he has to install .NET 4.5 despite the screenshot shows 4.6??

Comment: @TheGodfather, I updated my answer for clarity.