# Manually configure your web server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the attached error while trying to setup and run projects from the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

I have tried the following with no luck:

Tried uninstalling .net framework versions [VS 2012 web express error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q5HW.jpg)(in control panel the software framework is not getting listed)

Tried aspnet_regiis.exe but that produces the error that already framework 4.0 multi-targeting pack is available, Can anyone advice how to uninstall this package and install .net 4.5 in windows 10 machine.

Comment: Why you don't simply let the old version being installed and install the 4.5 version?

Comment: attachment is not attached correctly

Comment: This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301405/how-to-register-asp-net-on-windows-10

Comment: I am able to proceed by clicking on ok,  but wanted to know the reason behind the error so that I can resolve it. Added the screenshot for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register ASP.NET on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301405/how-to-register-asp-net-on-windows-10)